# An extra output is comming when i run my Program

Tags: java

The Program is 
 Running the Race
Write a program that asks for the names of three runners and the time, in minutes, it took
each of them to finish a race. The program should display the names of the runners in the
the order that they finished.

When i try to run My Code it gives me 4 outputs instead of 3 can anyone please help me with this program

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Rough {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner obj1=new Scanner(System.in);
     Scanner obj2=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner obj3=new Scanner(System.in);

    int racer1,racer2,racer3;

        System.out.println("enter racer 1 time in minutes");
        racer1=obj1.nextInt();

        System.out.println("enter racer 2 in minutes");
        racer2=obj2.nextInt();

        System.out.println("enter racer 3 in minutes ");
        racer3=obj3.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n");

        if(racer1> racer2 && racer1 > racer3   )
        {
            System.out.println(racer1 +"\n");
            if(racer2>racer3  )
            {
                System.out.println(racer2 +"\n");
                System.out.println(racer3 +"\n");
            }
            else
                System.out.println(racer3 +"\n");
                System.out.println(racer2 +"\n"       )   ;

        }
          else  if(racer2> racer1  && racer2 > racer3   )
        {
            System.out.println(racer2 +"\n"     );
            if(racer3>racer1  )
            {
                System.out.println(racer3 +"\n"      );
                System.out.println(racer1   +"\n"         );
            }
            else
                System.out.println(racer1);
                System.out.println(racer3);

        }
          else  if(racer3> racer1 && racer3 > racer2  )
        {
            System.out.println(racer3);
            if(racer2>racer1  )
            {
                System.out.println(racer2 +"\n"   );
                System.out.println(racer1  +"\n"        );
            }
            else
                System.out.println(racer1 +"\n"     );
                System.out.println(racer2 +"\n"     );

        } 

  ....................




























}
```

}

Comment: You have not added curly braces for `else` statement. If you avoid curly braces it would take only the first statement below of it and the rest statements will run regardless of the condition match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `{...}` for your `else` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write an else block like this. Your choice of indentation is confusing you.

```
else
    System.out.println(racer1);
    System.out.println(racer3);
```

This is equivalent to

```
else {
    System.out.println(racer1);
}
System.out.println(racer3); //always do this
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've been told by the partners you're missing the `{...}` on the else. I recommend a more understandable code like the following one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> racers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
            System.out.println("enter racer " + i + " time in minutes");
            racers.add(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
        }
        racers.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
        for (int racer : racers)
            System.out.println(racer + "\n");
    }
```